# How to rollback after openscap remediation

Tags: openscap

What is the best practice to rollback after a `openscap` remediate that made the system unstable other than to restore a system backup

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no automated way of reverting the changes done by the remediation. You would need to understand what the remediation does and revert it manually.

The only safe/easy way is to backup the system files prior applying the remediation, as you already said.